# Middleware between Languages

Tags: software

Let's say I have written a library containing many classes in C++. Obviously, I can call this library from C++ client programs.

But, now let's say I want to use another language for my client programs. Since my C++ library contains many classes, I don't want to redevelop them in the client language.

So, I would like to be able to call my C++ library classes from other languages.

Also, I want the solution to be portable across platforms. I don't want to be tied to one platform (such as .NET where any .NET language can call any other .NET language).

In the extreme case, this inter-language call feature would be required even from "managed" languages such as Java.

So, my question is: Is it possible to call a library function written in one language, from a program written in another language? If so, how?

Comment: The "only" in your question is the curx of the issue (I wouldn't describe it as only). The easiest way to go is to `export "C"` your interface and call it a day, if that will suffice.

Comment: The intention is not to call a C++ program from a C program. It is to call a program written in one language from _any other_ language. Eg: to call a C++ program from Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of the general use of "Middleware" is a little different to your description as it is not *primarily* about allowing libraries written in one language to be called from another.

I think that what you are looking for is tools that allow cross language bindings to be generate so as to allow libraries written in one language C++ in this case to be used in multiple other languages. A couple of examples of such tools are [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) and [Swig](http://www.swig.org/).

In both of the above tools you need to build your C++ libraries to run on your target platform and build an interface layer for the language(s) that you wish to provide bindings for but in the case of Boost *as far as I can see* you need to pay a lot of attention to how your library is constructed. SWIG on the other hand parses your interface (.h) files and produces bindings for the [supported](http://www.swig.org/compat.html#SupportedLanguages) target language(s) which include Tcl, Python, Perl, Guile, Java, Ruby, PHP, C#, R, Go, etc.

Comment: Adding language bindings for the target language looks like a promising approach and just what I am looking for. (i) Boost offers a category for "Inter-language support", but Python is the only language that can interface with C++, using this library. (ii) I don't know if Swig supports pre-compiled C++ headers (c) Java Native Interface (JNI) is a bridge between C++ and Java.